# AccessViolation ao alterar BorderStyle

Tags: delphi, redimensionamento

Olá!
Estou tentando alterar a propriedade borderstyle no evento `onCreate` do form, mas ocorre o erro `AccessViolation`, alguém sabe como posso resolver?

Meu código:

```
procedure TfmContasPagar.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  RedimensionarTela : String;
begin
      RedimensionarTela := TUtil.Sql.SQLLinha('SELECT REDIMENSIONAR_TELA FROM USUARIOS WHERE COD_USUARIO = ' + IntToStr(Codigo_Usuario), Database);
      if RedimensionarTela = 'N' then
         fmContasPagar.BorderStyle := bsSingle
      else
         fmContasPagar.BorderStyle := bsSizeable;
end;
```

Comment: O seu programa tem somente esta funcionalidade?

Comment: Não, mas não achei necessário colocar tudo aqui. A parte que ocorre erro é essa

Comment: A variável RedimensionarTela está sendo declarada aonde? Acho improvável que o erro seja na alteração do Border, a não ser que o escopo não tenha acesso a fmContasPagar. Access Violation ocorre ao tentar acessar um endereço de memória inexistente ou inacessível

Comment: Mas é que a tela funcionava normal, quando fui realizar essa alteração o erro começou a ocorrer

Comment: Tente debugar o código checando o conteúdo das variáveis antes, e no momento do erro. Tenha em mente que AccessViolation ocorre devido a um acesso de memória inexistente ou indevido. O erro não é reprodutível, o que torna difícil te responder.

Comment: Debuguei, como a variável está retornando 'N', é nessa condição que cai: `fmContasPagar.BorderStyle := bsSingle` e aí é que ocorre o erro

Comment: Utiliza `Self.BorderStyle` ao invés do modo que está fazendo para alterar a borda

Comment: Fiz assim como você disse, evitou o erro, mas não executou o comando, não trocou o borderStyle

Comment: poderia informar o código aonde você está criando o form TFmContasPagar ? A variável fmContasPagar se refere a TFmContasPagar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fiz da seguinte maneira:

```
procedure TfmContasPagar.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  RedimensionarTela : String;
begin
      RedimensionarTela := TUtil.Sql.SQLLinha('SELECT REDIMENSIONAR_TELA FROM USUARIOS WHERE COD_USUARIO = ' + IntToStr(Codigo_Usuario), Database);
      if RedimensionarTela = 'N' then
         Self.BorderStyle            := bsNone;
         Self.BorderIcons            := BorderIcons - [biMaximize];
         Self.Constraints.MaxHeight  := 570;
         Self.Constraints.MaxWidth   := 870;
      else
         Self.BorderStyle            := bsSizeable;
         Self.Constraints.MaxHeight  := 0;
         Self.Constraints.MaxWidth   := 0;
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
procedure TfmContasPagar.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  RedimensionarTela : String;
begin
  RedimensionarTela := TUtil.Sql.SQLLinha('SELECT REDIMENSIONAR_TELA FROM USUARIOS WHERE COD_USUARIO = ' + IntToStr(Codigo_Usuario), Database);
  if RedimensionarTela = 'N' then
  begin
    Self.BorderStyle            := bsNone;
    Self.BorderIcons            := BorderIcons - [biMaximize];
    Self.Constraints.MaxHeight  := 570;
    Self.Constraints.MaxWidth   := 870;
  end
  else
  begin
    Self.BorderStyle            := bsSizeable;
    Self.Constraints.MaxHeight  := 0;
    Self.Constraints.MaxWidth   := 0;
  end;
end;
```